# USB 3.0 to SATA external drive connected but not visible in Windows explorer

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, usb, external-hard-drive, sata

I have bought an internal drive (Seagate Barracuda with 5900 RPM) [like the following one](http://www.ebay.de/itm/Seagate-Barracuda-2-TB-Intern-5900RPM-ST32000542AS-/252574312481?) and want to connect it as an external drive. I also bought a [UGREEN USB 3.0 to SATA Converter](http://ugreen.com.cn/product-682-en.html) and a power supply with 12 Volt and 2 Amps.

The problem I am facing now is that the device manager on Windows sees the device as ASMT 2115 SCSI Disk Device but doesn’t connect it as a drive to my PC.

I'm using a Windows 10 system but also tried it on a Windows 7 system with the same result. Picture below:

[image]

Comment: Can you see your external HD in the list of available disks in Disk management?

Comment: Yes. The only thing I needed to do was to set the drive letter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign a drive letter to your external drive.

Hit <kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> type `diskmgmt.msc` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>

From there select your volume, right click it, and from the context menu Change Drive Letter and Paths.

Hit Change, Assign the following drive letter, select a drive letter and click OK.

Edit: As questioner added details, `diskmgmt.msc` had greyed out context menu, and couldn't change drive letters.

I later recommended to use [Paragon HFS+ for Windows](https://www.paragon-software.com/home/hfs-windows/). Once installed, Paragon HFS+ for Windows provides a high-speed read and write access to Mac-formatted partitions just as if it is a native Windows driver.

Comment: That's not possible, see the image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vZD2T.png), please.

Comment: Use [HFS](https://www.paragon-software.com/home/hfs-windows/) as recommended here [link](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/1ba097f6-8a0b-43d8-a826-928458c4ba15/change-drive-letter-and-paths-greyed-out-cant-assign-drive-letter?forum=w7itprohardware)

Comment: I only wanted to check the drive with Seagate Seatools but wasn't sure if it was connected in the right way.

Answer (score 0):

Your  UGREEN USB 3.0 to SATA Converter probably broken. I own that also. While I was formatting one of my hard disk using  UGREEN USB 3.0 to SATA Converter, it was interupted because sudden loss of the power supply. Next time i use the sata converter, its not working anymore.